# ROI signature creation error

Tags: qgis, python, image-classification, scp

I'm trying to run a maximum likelihood classification on a Landsat 8 mosaic to assess land cover, but I keep getting the same error during signature generation:

[image: Printscreen 1: SCP signature generation error.]

I never got this error before, and looking into the python scripts listed in the error message (i.e. scpdock.py and utils.py), it seems like it is a matter of ROI size:

[image: Printscreen 2: Python scripts showing the lines referenced by the error message.]

However, no matter what I do to the ROIs (enlarge, shrink, change the place I sample from in the image, draw different shapes), I always get the same error. So, I come asking for help in deciphering what's wrong. I don't know if this helps, but I'm using QGIS 3.4.4 with GRASS 7.6.0 on Windows 10 Home (v1607) 64-bit with python 3.6.